# how does featuretools DiffDatetimes work within the dfs?

Tags: featuretools

I've got the following dataset:

[image]

where:

- customer id represents a unique customer
- each customer has multiple invoices
- each invoice is marked by a unique identifier (Invoice)
- each invoice has multiple items (rows)

I want to determine the time difference between invoices for a customer. In other words, the time between one invoice and the next. Is this possible? and how should I do it with DiffDatetime?

Here is how I am setting up the entities:

```
es = ft.EntitySet(id="data")

es = es.add_dataframe(
    dataframe=df, 
    dataframe_name="items", 
    index = "items", 
    make_index=True,  
    time_index="InvoiceDate", 
)

es.normalize_dataframe(
    base_dataframe_name="items", 
    new_dataframe_name="invoices", 
    index="Invoice", 
    copy_columns=["Customer ID"], 
)

es.normalize_dataframe(
    base_dataframe_name="invoices",
    new_dataframe_name="customers",
    index="Customer ID",
)
```

I tried:

```
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_dataframe_name="invoices",
    agg_primitives=[],
    trans_primitives=["diff_datetime"],
    verbose=True,    
)
```

And also changing the target dataframe to invoices or customers, but none of those work.

The df that I am trying to work on looks like this:

```
es["invoices"].head()
```

[image]

And what I want can be done with pandas like this:

```
es["invoices"].groupby("Customer ID")["first_items_time"].diff()
```

which returns:

```
489434                NaT
489435    0 days 00:01:00
489436                NaT
489437                NaT
489438                NaT
               ...       
581582    0 days 00:01:00
581583    8 days 01:05:00
581584    0 days 00:02:00
581585   10 days 20:41:00
581586   14 days 02:27:00
Name: first_items_time, Length: 40505, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.

You can use the `groupby_trans_primitives` argument in the call to `dfs`.

Here is an example:

```py
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_dataframe_name="invoices",
    agg_primitives=[],
    groupby_trans_primitives=["diff_datetime"],
    return_types="all",
    verbose=True,    
)
```

The `return_types` argument is required since `DiffDatetime` returns a Feature with `Timedelta` logical type. Without specifying `return_types="all"`, `DeepFeatureSynthesis` will only return Features with numeric, categorical, and boolean data types.